# how to solve error in plsql that NO DATA FOUND

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

[image: Problem]

[image: code1/2]

[image: code2/2]

[image: error]

I am getting an error in this psql programming that : BIND VARIABLE "END" NOT DECLARED. Please help me with this.

Comment: in your line 49 is a : instead of a ;

Comment: ohh i corrected it now i am getting another error that in lie 20 "" this was not expected

Comment: attached a ss of error too

Comment: I have attached question too , if someone can help me with the ques , plz do hep\lp . thankyou

Comment: you use := to assign a value to variable, you cannot use := for a comparison. you should use = instead (without the : )

Comment: getting new error that no data found , just updated the screenshots

Comment: you should realy provide some sample data and expected output. what do you expect when your variable counter = 1 and there is not author with authorid = 1 in your table author?

Comment: I have attached what question i have , i have no sample data , expected output is in question itself , plz have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

there is absolutley no need for three loops, just join your data and loop once

```
begin

for i in (select b.bookid,
                 b.title,
                 p.publishername as publisher,
                 a.firstname || ' ' || a.lastname as author
            from books b
      inner join publisher p on b.publisherid = p.publisherid 
      inner join author a on b.author_id = a.authorid) loop
      
      dbms_output.put_line(i.bookid || ' ... ' || i.title || ' ... ' || i.publisher || ' ... ' || i.author);
end loop;

end;
```